# How to get random enum string?

Tags: swift

```
enum TrackingEvent: String {
    case notificationScreenLoaded = "Notification Screen"
    case homeScreenLoaded = "Home Screen"
    case homeScreenViewBill = "Home Screen View Bill Button"
    case homeScreenPayBill = "Home Screen Pay Bill Button"
    case homeScreenViewLastPayment = "Home Screen Last Payment Section" 
    case chartToggleUsage = "Charts Toggle"
    case chartExplanation = "Charts Explanation Screen"
}
```

for this example, how do I get a random string? So far what I search in StackOverflow examples the enum are all `UInt32` return type

Comment: refer **https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-pick-a-random-value-from-an-enum/**

Comment: @SandipND, wrong language. This is Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put all into an array and emit a random index item,

```
extension TrackingEvent {

    static func random() -> TrackingEvent {
        let all: [TrackingEvent] = [.notificationScreenLoaded,
                                    .homeScreenLoaded,
                                    .homeScreenViewBill,
                                    .homeScreenPayBill,
                                    .homeScreenViewLastPayment,
                                    .chartToggleUsage,
                                    .chartExplanation]
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random()) % all.count
        return all[randomIndex]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a function to get random `UInt32` with upper bound equal to the number of cases in the enum `TrackingEvent` and return the case based on a random number.

```
enum TrackingEvent: String {
    case notificationScreenLoaded = "Notification Screen"
    case homeScreenLoaded = "Home Screen"
    case homeScreenViewBill = "Home Screen View Bill Button"
    case homeScreenPayBill = "Home Screen Pay Bill Button"
    case homeScreenViewLastPayment = "Home Screen Last Payment Section"
    case chartToggleUsage = "Charts Toggle"
    case chartExplanation = "Charts Explanation Screen"

    static func random() -> TrackingEvent {
        let rand = arc4random_uniform(7)
        switch rand {
        case 1:
            return .homeScreenLoaded
        case 2:
            return .homeScreenViewBill
        case 3:
            return .homeScreenPayBill
        case 4:
            return .homeScreenViewLastPayment
        case 5:
            return .chartToggleUsage
        case 6:
            return .chartExplanation
        default:
            return .notificationScreenLoaded
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like 
`let random = TrackingEvent.random()`